# Inserting JSON Values into Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have `JSON` result like this :

```
[{"Januari":"0","Februari":"0","Maret":"0","April":"0","Mei":"7","Juni":"0","Juli":"0","Agustus":"0","September":"0","Oktober":"0","November":"0","Desember":"0"}]
```

How to insert values of `JSON` into `JavaScript` object?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myAreaChart");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
           label: "Visitor",
           data: [0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  //<-- insert values here
    }],
},
```

Comment: Enlighten us about what you tried thus-far, aside your main code you provided, to solve it yourself by editing it into your question and not in comments!... its called "showing effort" and is a good medicine against down-voters. End of "Triage Review" --> Requires "effort" and "editing".

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can extract values and parse them to `int` as below:

```js
var json = [{"Januari":"0","Februari":"0","Maret":"0","April":"0","Mei":"7","Juni":"0","Juli":"0","Agustus":"0","September":"0","Oktober":"0","November":"0","Desember":"0"}];
var numbers = Object.values(json[0]).map(s => parseInt(s, 10));
```

and finally change in your example:

```
data: numbers,
```